# Installation of FindBugs plugin with Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers

Tags: eclipse, plugins, installation, findbugs

I'm struggling to get the Eclipse FindBugs plugin to work and am sure there's a schoolboy error being made somewhere.

I extracted the file [findbugs-2.0.2-rc2.zip](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/findbugs/findbugs-2.0.2-rc2.zip?download)  to a local folder **C:\Program Files\findbugs-2.0.2-rc2** and running **findbugs.bat**, FindBugs works fine running it over a local Java (Eclipse) project.

I added the [FindBugs update site](http://findbugs.cs.umd.edu/eclipse), it found "FindBugs Feature, 2.0.1.20120712" and installed it. Restarting, right-clicking on an open Java Project doesn't display the "FindBugs" option (that [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1AJjwsuESno&feature=youtu.be&hd=1) shows).

I looked in **Window > Preferences** to try to find a way to inform the plugin of the local FindBugs installation (in Program Files), but couldn't find anything.

Uninstalling "FindBug Feature", I tried extracting the FindBugs Eclipse plugin [zip file](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/findbugs/edu.umd.cs.findbugs.plugin.eclipse_2.0.2.20121204.zip?download) into Eclipse's plugins folder, but after a restart, saw no difference.

**Help > About Eclipse > Installation Details > Installed Software** lists "FindBugs Feature 2.0.1.20120712".

Can anyone please offer a pointer on where I'm going wrong here? Thanks!

Windows 7, Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers Juno SR1, JDK 1.7.0_09, FindBugs 2.0.2-rc2

Comment: Today I upgraded my Eclipse Findbugs plugin 2.0.0 to version 2.0.2.20121210 and everything is working properly here. Did you check the Eclipse Error logs (Menu Help > About Eclipse > Installation Details > View Error Log)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @THelper.  
I've just upgraded and restarted, which all appeared to go OK, but still no "FindBugs" menu option when right-clicking on a project in either the Package or Project Explorer. The Error Log contains the line:  
  "!MESSAGE "FindBugs Feature" will be ignored because it is already installed."  
twice. Searching the contents of the Configuration window find absolutely NO reference to "findbugs" :-\

Answer (score 1):

As suggested above, problem is likely caused by not having appropriate write access to the C:\Program Files\Eclipse\plugins folder.

Solution: 
Close Eclipse. Restart Eclipse as Administrator (right click - Run as Administrator). Reinstall plugin. Restart Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Findbugs plugin wasn't installed properly and/or disabled by Eclipse. There can be several causes.

1. Multiple versions of the same plugin. To make sure this isn't the case, remove all Findbugs versions (installed manually and via the marketplace), and reinstall one (preferably via the marketplace). Watch for any warnings during installation.
2. There is a (dependency) conflict with another plugin. However, if this is the case I think Eclipse will warn in the log which other plugin is the cause of the conflict.
3. Rights problem. Make sure you have write permissions in the main Eclipse folder and all it's child folders.
4. I remember reading somewhere that installing Eclipse under the `C:\Program Files\` in Windows can also be causing problems. Try moving Eclipse to a different folder, e.g. `C:\Eclipse`

Answer (score 0):

Hi I also faced the similar problem  but from my own experience i can suggest you the solution :-

Plz ensure that you are using eclipse version 3.6 or higher. findbugs 2.0 is not compatible with Eclipse 3.5(Eclipse Galileo).

1) Plz extract the findbugs zip file into eclipse folder(wher your eclipse is installed). This will automatically move findbug plugins into eclipse plugins folder. Restart the eclipse and you will find findbugs option on right clicking on project.

2) if 1 step does not work plz remove all the findbug jars for the eclipse plugins folder and place the complete folder into the eclipse dropins folder. Restart the eclipse and you will see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these step's to make findbugs work in your eclipse.

1.Install FireBug plugin from marketplace.

```
Help->Eclipse Marketplace ->then search for FindBugs
```

2.Configure FindBug for your project

[using Maven](http://czetsuya-tech.blogspot.in/2012/04/how-to-setup-findbugs-with-maven-on.html)                                                  [Without Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395546/findbugs-not-showing-the-bugs-found)

This worked fine for me using eclipse juno.